# Dodged Bar Plots in ggplot - Defining colour by X axis as opposed to fill

Tags: ggplot2, colors, bar-chart, fill

Having some issue with dodged bar charts in ggplot. Essentially the only way I can dodge them is by changing fill to another variable, but I want to colour the paired plots by what they are on the x axis. 
Have included a dummy picture of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious here.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to use another not so useful variable to allow the dodge to happen. In the example below, I use color to separate them, but giving all of them the same color:

```
X = data.frame(Year=factor(rep(c(2016,2018),3)),
Sales=runif(6),Brand=rep(c("Toyota","Skoda","Ford"),each=2))

ggplot(X,aes(x=Brand,y=Sales,fill=Brand)) + 
geom_col(aes(col=Year),position="dodge",show.legend=FALSE) + 
scale_color_manual(values=c("black","black")) + 
geom_text(aes(label=Year,y=0.5*Sales),position=position_dodge2(1),angle=90)
```

[image]